# How to properly use mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a problem that I just can not wrap my head around.

When saving a name to mysql database if the name contains an apostrophy (single quote) I am getting unexpected results.

I have saved the name using `$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);`where `$con` is the connection string and `$name` is the name.  However instead of `$name` coming back as Peter O'Toole,  what I am getting is Peter O\

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong here?

Comment: If you use parameterized queries (like you should) you won't have to escape strings anymore.

Comment: most likely if I knew how to do so I would.  Can you either answer the question as asked OR provide the information to make your suggestion a bit more user friendly?

Comment: I commented as I don't have time atm to write a proper answer. This isn't anything new (released over 10 years ago), so searching for mysqli prepared statements or mysqli parameterized queries should give you a lot of writeups/tutorials.

Comment: What do you mean by this "Can you either answer the question as asked OR provide... "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change mysql_* to mysqli does not need use the same style, use prepared statements.

Old style

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `user`(name, email, password) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password'));

$mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

at `bind_param()` inform the type of date:

```
s => string
i => integer
d => double
b => blob
```

Prepared stamentes style

```
$db = new mysqli(...);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user`(name, email, password) VALUES(?,?,?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $email, $password);

if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo $db->error;
}
```

Comment: Ok got it now on to getting the information back out of the database